# tvOS Launch image not shown

Tags: xcode, tvos, launchimage

I create a project and add Launch image, but launch image not shown on tvOS

I build the project on Xcode 10.1. The launch image is not shown on 4K simulator, erase all content and settings of the simulator, change launch image, rename images, all of which don’t work.

I uploaded build to TestFlight, installed it on apple tv, opened app and did not show launch image. I restarted Apple TV and opened app again, then launch image appeared.

But we can't ask the end user to restart the Apple TV after installing the app.

Has anyone ever had the same issue? thanks

Here is the LaunchImage:
[bg.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIScY.png)
[bg@2x.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHrX3.png)

Here is the project:
https://github.com/haleyhe85/tvos.git